# Access Query Parameter Using Control on Navigation Subform

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have built an Access database which includes a Navigation form. One of the forms includes a combo box and a command button which, when clicked, opens a report filtered based on the value in the combo box. Here is a slightly simplified version of the query that's having the issue:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE site Like "*" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![comboBox] & "*";
```

Until today it was working fine. Now, when the button is clicked, an input box appears asking for a value to be supplied for the above parameter ([Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![comboBox]). Actually I am working on the front end of a split database, and a copy of the database still works fine and has the exact same where condition. The name of the combo box has not changed. I am actually having this problem with all the controls on any navigation subform. When the problem comes up in VBA code I am able to change it to Me.comboBox, but that won't work in a query parameter.

Since this is working on a copy of the database (but one without other changes to other forms that I'd rather not recreate) but not on this one, I'm not sure what the problem could be unless something is fundamentally wrong with this copy. Is there any way to find out what might have gone wrong? Or any way around this issue?

Comment: Hi, could you add the button's code?

Comment: It's actually not using VBA code in this case, just an embedded macro which opens the report. The query that the report is based on is what is failing - I've updated above to include the full query (a simplified version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of my navigation form and now everything's working. I still don't really understand why that made a difference since the old form name worked fine up until last week, but as long as it works I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are using macros, in which case your opening reference is a bit off.
As far as you have described, you got a navigation form, and in it there is obviously the navigationsubform which fas a combobox which is not linking its value properly.
Properly meaning you have to enter a value yourself because the control doesn't exist or isn't found.
In my tests I was able to reference through this macro, using openreport.
[image]
You use Text to get what its written in the combo, use value to get the underlying code if using hidden columns.

EDIT:

You have an extra form subclass in the where statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE site Like "*" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform]![comboBox].Text & "*";
```

Comment: Still nothing - I added that line to the macro and still get a pop-up asking for the parameter value. And as I mentioned above, this exact query/combobox/button/macro combination is working perfectly fine on an older version of the database front end.

Comment: Ok then, now I'm sure 100% the problem is in your query's SQL. Include the report recordsource query.

Comment: That's the query above.

Comment: Edited to fix query.